# CSS table make couples of columns equal

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a table in a page and each row has two  and two  elements like the following code:

```
<tr>
    <th></th>
    <td></td>
    <th></th>
    <td></td>
</tr>
```

What I want to do is have each pair of header and cell to have 50% width of the full table width but not by using fixed width. 
Any suggestions on that?

Answer (score 0):

`tr` stands for "Table Row". So if you want to have the 4 th/tr's split in to two different rows with 50% width, you will have to create two seperate table rows `tr`.

To make the cells stay at 50% regardless of the cells content you can apply `table-layout:fixed;` to the table.

```css
table {
 width:100%;
 table-layout:fixed;
}
th, td {
  border:1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
      <th>hello one hello one hello one hello one hello one hello one hello one hello one</th>
      <td>hello two</td>
      <th>hello one hello one hello one hello one hello one hello one hello one hello one</th>
      <td>hello four</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<br><br>
<table>
  <tr>
      <th>hello one hello one hello one hello one hello one hello one hello one hello one</th>
      <td>hello two</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>hello three hello three hello three hello three hello three hello three hello three hello three</th>
    <td>hello four</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```